# Attempting to determine decimals places using CHARINDEX, getting: Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, ssms

I use this piece of code all the time on many objects when trying to determine the number of decimals after the '.'.  The target system I am moving data to can only handle 2 d.p.  So we I find data with >2 d.p. I multiply by 10, 100, 1000 and also multiply the 'price per' field value by the same factor.

```
SELECT 
    HQPROD, [HQPR1],
    Decimals = CASE Charindex('.', [HQPR1])
                  WHEN 0 THEN 0
                  ELSE LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [HQPR1], 128)) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
               END 
FROM 
    [SM_REP].[dbo].[BPCSF64_HQT]) EDP ON P.HQPROD = EDP.HQPROD
```

The column datatype I am working with is `DECIMAL(15,5)`.

Sample data:

```
HQPROD         HQPR1
--------------------------
47001-RM64     175.89900
47001-T06OX      5.84500
47002-20T       80.44700
47002-T24       98.10300
47002-T32      144.07000
47003-01         1.54000
47003-02         1.54000
47003-03         0.51000
```

Error message:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: Are there any negative values? The `reverse()` would put the `-` sign at the end of the string which then cannot be casted to a float.

Comment: Why not just multiple everything by 1000 and forget about such tricks?

Comment: Some target fields will be too big if I just multiply by 1000.  There is 1 value in the table with a negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
HQPR1, 
Decimals = 

CASE WHEN HQPR1 > 0 THEN
       CASE Charindex('.', [HQPR1])
              WHEN 0 THEN 0
              ELSE LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [HQPR1], 128)) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
        END 
 ELSE 
     CASE Charindex('.', [HQPR1])
              WHEN 0 THEN 0
              ELSE LEN(CAST(CAST(REVERSE(     Stuff((CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [HQPR1], 128)),1,1,'' )) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
      END 
 END
```

This will work also for negative numbers, which as sticky bit said,could be causing your error.